# RedirectMatch 301 - Only Directory Exclude Files, Sub Directories, Query Strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have looked all around but everything seems to be the opposite of what I want. What I'm trying to do is just redirect directory excluding everything after directory URL. So I have this which is working

```
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/ http://www.mynewblog.com/
```

but I need it to exclude(not redirect) a query string appended after directory or files and sub-directories. So I want to access these urls still

```
http://www.myoldblog.com/blog/?wpdmact=process
http://www.myoldblog.com/blog/page/2
http://www.myoldblog.com/blog/page.php
```

But everything after `/blog/` is still getting redirected. So is there a way to exclude this in htaccess file. Thanks and sorry if someone already posted answer, I could not find.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^wpdmact=process
RewriteCond $1 !^page/2
RewriteCond $1 !^page.php
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.mynewblog.com/ [L,R=301]
```

You'll need to use mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias if you want to match against the query string, but this will redirect everything starting with `/blog/` *except8 if the query string is `wpdmact=process` or if the following paths are `page/2` or `page.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ http://www.mynewblog.com/ [R,L]
```

Please note that for the above rules to work, you need to enable the `mod_rewrite`. While `RedirectMatch` directive is provided with the `mod_alias` module, rewrites are done with a separate module.